# Finding a user's home from bash

Tags: linux, bash, samba, puppet

I'm trying to get the value of a user's home from a puppet script. This particular user is a Samba user, not a local one, with the username of the form `DOMAIN\user`.

I've tried the following, with no success:

- `echo "~DOMAIN\\user"` ( outputs the exact input )
- `getent passwd DOMAIN\\user` ( outputs nothing, the user is not even listed using getent passwd )

I'm surprised that getent did not work, since it is configured to do so:

```
$ cat /etc/nsswitch.conf | grep passwd
passwd: compat winbind
```

A simple C program using the `getpwnam` works, but that's going to be problematic to include and use from puppet.

How can I retrieve the user's home from puppet or a simple shell command?

Comment: Try getent with DOMAIN+user

Comment: Sorry, that does now work either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how Samba figures in this, but otherwise...

```
finger -mlp $USER | grep Directory | cut -f2 -d ' '
```

(although this will ned some tweaks to handle spaces in the path)

Comment: Aha, this does work! Does the `finger` command require extra privileges or setup to run locally? I recall that it does to run it remotely

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "remotely" in this context. It only really makes sense running it on the machine where the user is expected to login - since the home dir is subject to the configuration of that machine as well as any centrally stored credentials.

Comment: I was thinking on whether it requires fingerd or something similar. However, running it through strace shows that it does not need that.

Answer (score 0):

To make the `getent` call work, just enclose the argument in single quotes `'`:

```
getent passwd 'DOMAIN\user'
```